# How to run SQL statement from Databricks cluster

Tags: sql-server, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I have an Azure Databricks cluster that processes various tables and then as a final step I push these table into an Azure SQL Server to be used by some other processes.  I have a cell in databricks that looks something like this:

```
def generate_connection():
  jdbcUsername = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Azure-Key-Vault-Scope", key = "AzureSqlUserName")
  jdbcPassword = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Azure-Key-Vault-Scope", key = "AzureSqlPassword")
  connectionProperties = {
    "user" : jdbcUsername,
    "password" : jdbcPassword,
    "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
  }
  return connectionProperties

def generate_url():
  jdbcHostname = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Azure-Key-Vault-Scope", key = "AzureSqlHostName")
  jdbcDatabase = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Azure-Key-Vault-Scope", key = "AzureSqlDatabase")
  jdbcPort = 1433
  return "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)


def persist_table(table, sql_table, mode):
  jdbcUrl = generate_url();
  connectionProperties = generate_connection()
  table.write.jdbc(jdbcUrl, sql_table, properties=connectionProperties, mode=mode)

persist_table(spark.table("Sales.OpenOrders"), "Sales.OpenOrders", "overwrite")
persist_table(spark.table("Sales.Orders"), "Sales.Orders", "overwrite")
```

This works as expected.  The problem that I have is that the Orders table is very large and only a small fraction of the rows could possible change each day, so what I want to do is change the overwrite mode to the append mode and change the data frame from being the entire table to just the rows that could have changed.  All of this I know how to do easily enough, but what I want to do is run a simple SQL statement against the Azure SQL database to remove the rows that are already going to be there, so that they possibly changed rows will be inserted back.

I want to run a SQL statement against the Azure SQL database like

```
Delete From Sales.Orders Where CreateDate >= '01/01/2019'
```

Comment: You should be able to run the SQL statement in a cell with the %sql magic.

Comment: No I don’t want to run that sql against the cluster I want to run it against the remote sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the pyodbc library. You can connect and use sql statements.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                       'SERVER=mydatabe.database.azure.net;'
                       'DATABASE=AdventureWorks;UID=jonnyFast;'
                       'PWD=MyPassword')

# Example doing a simple execute
conn.execute('INSERT INTO Bob (Bob1, Bob2) VALUES (?, ?)', ('A', 'B'))
```

Unfortunately to get it working on databricks is a bit of a pain. I wrote a blog post a while back which should help. 
https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark

Comment: hi mate, tried this but getting a `file not found` error - unsure what the problem is as I'm able to connect to my dB using JDBC?

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my findings.

1) pyodbc - I asked a Microsoft Technical Support and got the answer is as follows:

```
####========================================================
### cell 1: install pyodbc
####========================================================
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc

####========================================================
### cell 2: connect
####========================================================
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                       'SERVER=xxxxx.database.windows.net;'
                       'DATABASE=xxxxx;UID=xxxxx;'
                       'PWD=xxxxx')

####========================================================
### cell 3: create table
####========================================================
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE dbo.Bob (Bob1 VARCHAR(30), Bob2 VARCHAR(30))')

####========================================================
### cell 4: insert into table
####========================================================
conn.execute('INSERT INTO dbo.Bob (Bob1, Bob2) VALUES (?, ?)', ('A', 'B'))
```

Notes: 
a) Runtime: 6.2 (Scala 2.11, Spark 2.4.4)
b) This Runtime version supports only Python 3.

2) [Spark connector for Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector) - While googling a solution for installing pyodbc, I found this one. I like this one better and am going to try it out.