# Execute msdb stored procedure with pyspark jdbc

Tags: jdbc, pyspark, azure-databricks

PySpark has `df = spark.read.jdbc()`

It also has `df.write.jdbc()`

Does it have some fashion of `spark.{execute or call or whatever}.jdbc()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run SQL statement from Databricks cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55580862/how-to-run-sql-statement-from-databricks-cluster)

Comment: No but you could use third party packages if the data is not too big https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark

Comment: @sramalingam24 Yeah.  But I was hoping to keep all my data access in one basket, if you will let me say it that way.